# How to retrieve all datas from Listbox when selected item changed

Tags: c#, listbox

I gave datatable as datasource to Lisbox. 
That tables fields are ID, Subject, Texts and ID is an Unique field(PK).
But Subject shown as DisplayMember.

Here is my datasource giving code:

```
lbTexts.DataSource = mDataSet.Tables["Story"];
lbTexts.DisplayMember = "Subject";
```

i want to know which rows the user has selected and what is the Unique value.
i find it with 10 rows of code. But i hope there is a simple way to find it.

Comment: Try with lbTexts.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: Post your code so we know what you are trying to do, you keep saying thats not what you are looking for but your question is that that clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the ValueMember property and set it to Id, you can use the SelectedValue parameter without needing the entire dataset. You're also guaranteed to not get resorting errors where the selected index in the list doesn't match the index in the data.

```
lbTexts.ValueMember = "Id";

// Later
int selectedId = Int32.Parse(lbTexts.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: +1, @Bekhbayar you should accept this as best answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.selecteditem%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get the currently selected item, and use [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to get the value.

**Example of selectedItem**:

```
String value = lbTexts.SelectedItem.Value;
```

**Example of selectedValue:**

```
String txt = lbTexts.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: well, that's not really what i wanted to know. But anyway thanks. I want to know what is the 'ID' field value of SelectedItem

Comment: You get all the fields of the selectedItem using this though so you do get the ID?! You put a loop round it obviously for 10 times or however many you want and it does what you asked in the question.

Comment: i just tried like following:
      string str = (lbTexts.SelectedItem as DataRow)["StoryID"].ToString();
but it gives object reference exception. :D how should i exactly get the value

Comment: If your post your code in the question we can help you better :)

Comment: seems i got it. :D
`string str = (lbTexts.DataSource as DataTable).Rows[lbTexts.SelectedIndex]["ID"].ToString();`

Comment: I think selectedIndex gives you the index value of where the selected item is, I don't think it's giving you back the actual ID is it?

Comment: no no... it's not actual ID. It's just index. It won't work properly if i sort my datatable, unless then i can use it. Or i could sort my datatable before give it to listbox as datasource. that's kind a solution i think

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
string value = lbTexts.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: well, that's not really what i wanted to know. But anyway thanks. I want to know what is the 'ID' field value of SelectedItem.

Comment: at last i wrote following and it works great. Is it correct :D
string str = (lbTexts.DataSource as DataTable).Rows[lbTexts.SelectedIndex]["Subject"].ToString();

Comment: @Bekhbayar,  No, That is not the right way of doing. Please use SlectedItem as mentioned in my post. Thanks